# XCUITest : Know language of app/iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, testing

I have a scenario where there are different users based on the language.
How do I determine the language of the iPhone/Simulator/App so that I know what login to use.

For example

- if the language is en-us user Eng_User
- if language is ru then use Ru_User

Is there a way in XCUITest after launching the application that I know the language being user

Can I set a property in app delegate and use it later??
I tried setting app.accessibilityLanguage in appDelegate but couldn't use it in the test as the value returned was nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 9, you can set the language for an XCUITest suite in

```
Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Test -> Options -> Application Language
```

Unfortunately I don't see a way to read that back right now. You could pass in an environment variable, though, that matches the language. Under

```
Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Test -> Arguments -> Environment Variables
```

set a key / value for your test local and language that matches the setting in Options. You can read environment variables in your test code with `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` ie

```
let language = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["locale"]
```

More on localization testing in Xcode 9 can be found here:

http://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2017/06/whats-new-in-localization-in-xcode-9-ios-11/